# Expand, transpose and de-aggregate a dataset using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where there are several categories with number counts for each category.  I would like to transform this set and show a distinct count for each category. I would also like to add a new 'count' column.  The newly generated counts go off of the date column. Example how many distinct alphas are there in q1 for ID A:  2 and so on.

**Data**

```
ID  date    alpha   beta    gamma   
A   q1      2       2       1   
B   q1      2       2       3   
C   q1              
D   q2      2
```

**Desired**

```
ID  type    date    count           
A   alpha   q1      alpha1          
A   alpha   q1      alpha2          
A   beta    q1      beta1           
A   beta    q1      beta2           
A   gamma   q1      gamma1          
B   alpha   q1      alpha1          
B   alpha   q1      alpha2          
B   beta    q1      beta1           
B   beta    q1      beta2           
B   gamma   q1      gamma1          
B   gamma   q1      gamma2          
B   gamma   q1      gamma3          
C
D   alpha   q2      alpha1
D   alpha   q2      alpha2
```

**Doing**

I believe I may have to use the code below, in addition to the **melt** function.

```
df.melt(id_vars= ['ID', 'date'],
        var_name = 'type',
        value_name = 'count'
```

However, I am not able to expand the values into distinct counts

Any suggestions will be helpful. I am still researching this.

Comment: would be helpful if you provided the source code for your sample dataframe -> `df.head(10).to_dict('records')` importing your data at the moment requires manually adjusting for the empty cells

Comment: Oh ok I provided the  sample dataset. Do you mean the sample output ? I will try

Comment: yea, I figured it out ... just seemed simpler with source code ... no worries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Melt the dataframe

```
df=pd.melt(df.replace("",0), id_vars=['ID','date'], value_vars=['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']).sort_values(by='ID')
```

Repeat rows by values of the column value

```
newdf = (pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values,df.value.astype(int),axis=0))).rename(columns={0:'ID',1:'date',2:'type',3:'count'})
```

Update Count to have a concat of type and count of type in each ID

```
 newdf=newdf.assign(count=newdf['type']+(newdf.groupby(['ID','type'])['type'].cumcount()+1).astype(str))
    

    ID date   type   count
0   A   q1  alpha  alpha1
1   A   q1  alpha  alpha2
2   A   q1   beta   beta1
3   A   q1   beta   beta2
4   A   q1  gamma  gamma1
5   B   q1  alpha  alpha1
6   B   q1  alpha  alpha2
7   B   q1   beta   beta1
8   B   q1   beta   beta2
9   B   q1  gamma  gamma1
10  B   q1  gamma  gamma2
11  B   q1  gamma  gamma3
12  D   q2  alpha  alpha1
13  D   q2  alpha  alpha2
```

Comment: Happy to help further if needed. Just a word of caution, avoid using reserved words like type in you columns

Comment: Thank you - it is saying:  TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' I am troubleshooting this

Comment: Maybe due to some of my values being NAN? in my full dataset- should I convert the NANs in the dataset to 0 first?

Comment: Fillna(), alternatively resend a new data sample

Comment: ok would I put the fillna() at the end of the second code statement?

Comment: Cant tell unless I know which line throws the error

Comment: Try introduce `df['value'].fillna(0, inplace=True)` after `df=pd.melt(df.replace("",0), id_vars=['ID','date'], value_vars=['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']).sort_values(by='ID')`

Comment: ok troubleshooting now, the first line works, I think it is the second line where I need to add this

Comment: oh, I think the counts are off, because gamma 5,6,7 should be  gamma 1,2,3...

Comment: Edited it for you. Let me no if this suffices

Answer (score 1):

Uses pandas version 1.2.4  ...

First we melt,
then get rid of nulls, since they are not needed in the final output.

Next move the dataframe into a series by setting as index and squeezing.

This allows us to `repeat` the series with the `count`.

After that we then get the count per group, before merging them into one column

```
temp = (df.melt(['ID', 'date'],  
                ignore_index = False, 
                value_name = 'count')
          .dropna()
          .sort_index()
          .set_index(['ID', 'date', 'variable'], append = True)
          .squeeze())

(temp.repeat(temp)
     .reset_index(['ID', 'date', 'variable'])
     .assign(count = lambda df: df.variable + 
                                df.groupby(['ID', 'variable'])
                                  .variable.cumcount()
                                  .add(1)
                                  .astype(str))
     .reset_index(drop = True))


   ID date variable   count
0   A   q1    alpha  alpha1
1   A   q1    alpha  alpha2
2   A   q1     beta   beta1
3   A   q1     beta   beta2
4   A   q1    gamma  gamma1
5   B   q1    alpha  alpha1
6   B   q1    alpha  alpha2
7   B   q1     beta   beta1
8   B   q1     beta   beta2
9   B   q1    gamma  gamma1
10  B   q1    gamma  gamma2
11  B   q1    gamma  gamma3
12  D   q2    alpha  alpha1
13  D   q2    alpha  alpha2
```

Comment: Hi @sammywemmy where does the 'variable' come from? are you creating this? - Don't I have to add the 'alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'

Comment: when you melt there is a default name 'variable'. You dont have to specifically list out alpha beta gamma if you know those are the columns that will be transposed. Have a look at [melt docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) for more detailed info.

Comment: I am getting this error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'variable'  -- Please assist, because your output is showing the desired

Comment: hmm maybe id_vars perhaps?

Comment: you'll have to debug ... at what line does it trigger the error ... if you comment out the assign section, does it give u an error?

Comment: ok I will debug, it just says there is no 'variable' in the dataframe... .assign(count = lambda df: df2.variable +  .... I will troubleshoot. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
df = df.set_index(['ID', 'date']).stack().astype(int).apply(range).explode().reset_index(
    name='count').assign(count=lambda x: x.level_2 + (x['count'] + 1).astype(str))
```